# Bootstrap 5 - open nav tab programmatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using bootstrap 5 for a vue project. I have created a component that have two nav [tabs](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs/#using-data-attributes) to display some contents and I need to show the second tab if the user perform an action. I'm using the data attribute to trigger the normal tabs visualization but I want to display the second tab programmatically after the user action. Can anyone help me? I've tried with this code but didn't work

```
    <nav class="nav mt-2 mb-2" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-link active p-0 pr-2" role="tab" href="#program-tab" data-toggle="tab">Info</a>
      <a class="nav-link p-0 pr-2" role="tab" href="#download-tab" data-toggle="tab">Downloads</a>
    </nav>

<div class="row tab-pane fade m-0" id="download-tab" role="tabpanel" ref="downloadTab">...</div>
```

```
import { Tab } from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'

data() {
  return {
    tab: null
  }
},
methods: {
  openTab() {
    this.tab = new Tab()
    console.log(this.tab)
    this.tab.getInstance(this.$refs.downloadTab).show()
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try `this.tab = new Tab(this.$refs.downloadTab); this.tab.show()`?

Comment: no, I didn't tried yet, but I will do a test

Comment: please share the template or a running code

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I get this error in console `bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null` see the edited question